# How do I import X3D models into my Java code?

Tags: java, x3d

I'm working on a project and I have multiple X3D models that I need to use in the final project outcome. I'm using Java as the main programming language and I've been told that I can import the X3D models into the Java project and I don't know how to.

Comment: `Java` is a programming language, that means you can do whatever you can imagine with it. `x3d` is a markup language, which means any sensible SAX or DOM parser should be able to parse the documents - What you do with that data in turn is up to you.

Comment: it is impossible to import a x3d model in java code

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463231/how-to-generate-jaxb-classes-from-xsd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a look at xj3d. It builds a scene-graph from X3D file.

The latest version can be found at http://sourceforge.net/projects/xj3d/, the official site (http://www.xj3d.org/) does not seems to have been updated recently.

EDIT:
Replying to comment above (I don't have enough reputation to comment)
There is also a binary format for X3D, so standard XML parsers won't work with it.

Comment: I've had a look into Xj3D and I've downloaded it and tried to implement it into my project but I'm still having trouble trying to get into the project

Comment: Hum,  I've checked the Javadoc found there (I don't know if it is up to date or not): https://savage.nps.edu/Xj3D.nps/docs/javadoc/

I think that you can load the file using org.xj3d.loaders.ogl.X3DLoader. Then it gives you an Aviatrix3d scene graph you can navigate in. But there are probably other solutions.

But I suggest that you contact xj3d developpers directly. I'm sure that they can direct you to some good docs/tutorials.