# How to create pojo classes from XSD?

Tags: java, spring, maven, xsd, pojo

I am using Spring maven plugin, I want to create POJO classes from specified xml schema in particular folder. I tried with `xjc` command through java code, but its not generating that classes. secondly, I tried with `jaxb`, but its dealing with `xml` file not a `xsd` schema while marshell/unmarshelling. I think this not a way to create POJO from `xsd`.

What is a correct way to generate classes from xsd in java?

below is XSD

```
   <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <xs:element name="Employee">
   <xs:complexType>
   <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="empId" type="xs:long"/>
    <xs:element name="lastName" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="salary" type="xs:integer"/>
    <xs:element name="address">
    <xs:complexType>
       <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
         <xs:element name="street" type="xs:string"/>
         <xs:element name="zipcode" type="xs:integer"/>
         <xs:element name="privatePhoneNo">
           <xs:complexType>
             <xs:sequence>
                 <xs:element name="privateMobile" type="xs:string"/>
                 <xs:element name="privateLandline" type="xs:string"/>
             </xs:sequence>
           </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
     </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
 </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
 </xs:schema>
```

Comment: We use a tool called XMLBeans in our production code.  It is deprecated, but has worked well for us.

Comment: can you please explain more. how to use it?

Comment: You can't "create classes at run time". You can however create classes at build time (or manually before that) from an XML Schema (XSD) file, using XJC. I don't know how you do that using maven, though, but have you tried running the [xjc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/xjc.html) command yourself?

Comment: As @Andreas mentioned, you can't create classes at runtime, but you can create classes during the build.  See [here](https://xmlbeans.apache.org/) for more information.  Keep in mind that XMLBeans was retired as of about one year ago.  So you might want to use a more modern framework.

Comment: @Andreas yes I will change my question it should generate at build time. and I tried with xjc its working when I am manually firing that command on cmd but through java code its not generating that classes.

Comment: String[]  createPojo= new String [] {
        "CMD.EXE",
        "/C",
        "cd \"C:\\training_1\\mongo-starter\" && dir","xjc -d target -p generated-sources Xmlschema.xsd" };
Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(createPojo);
int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();

Comment: What do you mean "through java code"? Why are you running Java code **at build time**? The build should be done with Ant, Maven, Gradle, or other build tool, and the build *produces* Java class files to be executed at run time.

Comment: through java code only I want to generated classes from the given XSD. XSD will changes  so I want to configure something which through I can genrated that pojo class according to XSD

Comment: classes from XSD can (and MUST) be autogenerated by your IDE using JAXB plugin.... http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071784/enterprise-java/java-xml-mapping-made-easy-with-jaxb-2-0.html

Comment: `JAXB `has to work whichever may be the way you trying, you seem to be doing something wrong. Why don't you share the `xsd` file, we can try to generate POJO from it and get back.

Comment: yes @Bikram Kundu  Actually I am not getting how to use jaxb through java code for pojo creation I dont want to create it manually by creating jaxb project then using that generate pojo functions of IDE.I am adding XSD

Comment: Possible duplicate of
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463231/how-to-generate-jaxb-classes-from-xsd

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> My recommendation is to go with `JAXB`.

I have tested it in `eclipse`, works well for me. My suggestion is try generating the POJO from `command line` or with the help of `eclipse`. Once successful configure it with `maven` to generate the POJO `build time`.

There are several tutorials to learn this, please follow the below link(s) based upon your preference:

- [Generate POJO Class from XSD in Eclipse](http://www.javawebtutor.com/articles/jaxb/jaxb_java_class_from_xsd.html)
- [Generate POJO class from XSD Schema command line](http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java/jaxb/generate-java-class-from-xml-schema-using-jaxb-xjc-command/)
- [Generate POJO Classes from XSD using `XJC` Maven Plugin](http://www.journaldev.com/1312/how-to-generate-java-classes-from-xsd-using-xjc-maven-plugin)

Also the youtube links:

- [Youtube video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zgblFjA-5Ks)
- [Youtube tutorial using maven](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qX-Erp8a3wo)

I hope it helps!

Feel free to comment if you encounter any issue.

Comment: yes I gone thrugh this all. I dont want to create those classes manually or by the cmd it should be generate from java code I am using Spring .Actually if our XSD file is same then it works fine but in my case XSD file will change time to time user will give us a xsd file and from that I want to create classes so I dont want to generate it manually.is there any onather way? can we run that cmd command through Spring ?

Comment: I have mentioned about how to achieve it in build time using maven, this should help you. Check the third link! I don't think you can achieve it run time, at least I am not aware of anything like that!

Comment: yes In third link we have to configure pakage path and file then it will generate those classes at build time. but is ther any onather way to configure without using plugins?

Comment: Please let me know if it is not helping you!

Comment: Its Helping me but my requirement is little bit different instead of configuring in plugin I want to take that XSD file from user . so I tried to run that XJC command through java code but that is not working

Comment: Thank you for the third link :) exactly what I needed

Comment: looks like the page refer by 3rd link is move [https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/jaxb2-maven-plugin-xjc-example-generate-java-classes-xsd](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/jaxb2-maven-plugin-xjc-example-generate-java-classes-xsd)

Answer (score 8):

**jaxb2-maven-plugin**

Using jaxb2-maven-plugin is the easiest way. Define the plugins as below :

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/xsd/</schemaDirectory>
                <schemaFiles>MARC21slim.xsd</schemaFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and execute :

```
mvn jaxb2:xjc
```

the generated files will be located in  `target\generated-sources\jaxb`

Comment: Awesomely simple. Thanks mate

Answer (score 6):

One simple way to convert `.xsd` files to Java file is [xjc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/xjc.html) tool. Just execute the following command in the same working directory:

```
xjc test.xsd
```

Comment: Here is an example of xjc https://thoughts-on-java.org/generate-your-jaxb-classes-in-second/

Answer (score 2):

`jaxb2-maven-plugin` version 2 changes how the configure.

The following will run xjc on everything in `src/main/resource` and put it `com.yourcompany.xsd`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <sources>
            <source>src/main/resources</source>
        </sources>
        <packageName>com.yourcompany.xsd</packageName>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Check out the implicit behavior in https://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v2.5.0/example_xjc_basic.html