# wsdl2java: how to control naming of generated Java list properties?

Tags: java, cxf, wsdl2java

I was using some old CXF 2.x `wsdl2java` version and it used to generate Java properties like `List deny` for a `<deny/>` element:

```
class MyDto {
  List deny;
```

Then I switched to a higher version `org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:2.6.16` and it started to generate them as `List denies`, adding the plural:

```
class MyDto {
  List denies;
```

I tried 3.x - it's still there. The problem with this change is it has introduced non obvious bugs into existing codebase. So I'd like to revert it back.

*Question:* How can I control the style Java properties are generated?

Comment: It's JAXB + XJC actually generating DTO not CXF itself, And here is answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463231/how-to-generate-jaxb-classes-from-xsd - modify XSD or stop using `<xjc:simple/>`.