# convert xml to java object using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, pojo

I have the following XML and want to convert it into Java object.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datasources xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema http://docs.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema/datasources_1_0.xsd">
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/FDMS_DemoDS" pool-name="FDMS_DemoDS">
      <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</connection-url>
      <driver>com.mysql</driver>
      <pool>
          <max-pool-size>60</max-pool-size>
      </pool>
      <security>
          <user-name>fduser</user-name>
          <password>fdms!</password>
      </security>
  </datasource>
</datasources>
```

I am not sure what will be my corresponding java class when I use JAXB to convert it.

This is what I have tried so far based on my understanding:

```
 @XmlRootElement
public class Datasources {

    String connectionUrl;
    String maxPoolSize;
    String driver;

    public String getConnectionUrl() {
        return connectionUrl;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setConnectionUrl(String connectionUrl) {
        this.connectionUrl = connectionUrl;
    }

    public String getMaxPoolSize() {
        return maxPoolSize;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setMaxPoolSize(String maxPoolSize) {
        this.maxPoolSize = maxPoolSize;
    }

    public String getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setDriver(String driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }
}
```

Comment: @dabadaba I am not able to create POJO for given xml.

Comment: Your Scheam is there [datasources_1_0.xsd](http://docs.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema/datasources_1_0.xsd). Download the file and generate your java file via jaxb.

Comment: The class you posted is more for the `Datasource` object than the`Datasources` object.

Comment: @Berger That is where I am confused and not able to create appropriate POJO. Can you guide me on this.?

Comment: @Patrick How to create java file using just xsd ?

Comment: Which IDE do you use?

Comment: @Patrick Eclipse Luna

Comment: look here: [how-to-generate-jaxb-classes-from-xsd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463231/how-to-generate-jaxb-classes-from-xsd) and here [XJCFacade issue](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/206797/)

Comment: @Patrick can you tell me how can I write POJO class for corresponding XML instead of generarting them automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the Java classes with the JAXB annotation.
This is not 100% accurate but it may help you.

**Datasources.java**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
   "datasource"
})
public class Datasources {

    @XmlElement(name = "datasource")
    private List<Datasource> datasources;

    public List<Datasource> getDatasources() {
        if (datasource == null) {
            datasources = new ArrayList<Datasource>();
        }
        return datasources
    }
}
```

**Datasource.java**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
   "connection-url",
   "driver",
   "pool",
   "security"
})
public class Datasource {

    @XmlElement(name = "connection-url")
    private String connectionUrl;
    @XmlElement(name = "driver")
    private String driver;
    @XmlElement(name = "pool")
    private Pool pool;
    @XmlElement(name = "security")
    private Security security;

    public String getConnectionUrl() {
        return connectionUrl;
    }

    public void setConnectionUrl(String value) {
        this.connectionUrl = value;
    }

    public String getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    public void setDriver(String value) {
        this.driver = value;
    }

    public Pool getPool() {
        return pool;
    }

    public void setPool(Pool value) {
        this.pool = value;
    }

    public Security getSecurity() {
        return security;
    }

    public void setSecurity(Security value) {
        this.security = value;
    }
}
```

**Pool.java**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
   "max-pool-size"
})
public class Pool {
    @XmlElement(name = "max-pool-size")
    private String maxPoolSize;

    public String getMaxPoolSize() {
        return maxPoolSize;
    }

    public void setMaxPoolSize(String value) {
        this.maxPoolSize = value;
    }
}
```

**Security.java**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
   "user-name",
   "password"
})
public class Security {
    @XmlElement(name = "user-name")
    private String username;
    @XmlElement(name = "password")
    private String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String value) {
        this.username = value;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String value) {
        this.password = value;
    }
}
```